# Elf read symbols

Tags: c, elf

I'm trying to read symbols from the .symtab section but it seems that I'm not getting this section the right way. I've been reading the spec and searching online for a while now.

Why does symtab[i].st_name read 0 for every entry ?
The executable I'm reading has symbols.

```
            Elf64_Half shdr_tab_size = ehdr->e_shentsize * ehdr->e_shnum;
            Elf64_Shdr shdr_tab[shdr_tab_size];

            rewind(infos.fp);
            fseek(infos.fp, ehdr->e_shoff, SEEK_SET);
            fread(&shdr_tab, 1, ehdr->e_shentsize * ehdr->e_shnum, infos.fp);

            char *shdr_names;
            shdr_names = malloc(shdr_tab[ehdr->e_shstrndx].sh_size);
            if (shdr_names != NULL) {
                fseek(infos.fp, shdr_tab[ehdr->e_shstrndx].sh_offset, SEEK_SET);
                fread(shdr_names, 1, shdr_tab[ehdr->e_shstrndx].sh_size, infos.fp);
            }

            Elf64_Shdr shdr_strtab = get_section_hdr(".strtab", shdr_tab, shdr_names, ehdr->e_shnum);
            Elf64_Shdr shdr_symtab = get_section_hdr(".symtab", shdr_tab, shdr_names, ehdr->e_shnum);

            if (shdr_symtab.sh_type == SHT_SYMTAB) {

                Elf64_Sym *symtab = malloc(shdr_symtab.sh_size);
                fseek(infos.fp, shdr_symtab.sh_offset, SEEK_SET);
                fread(symtab, 1, shdr_symtab.sh_size, infos.fp);

                char *strtab = malloc(shdr_strtab.sh_size);
                fseek(infos.fp, shdr_tab[shdr_symtab.sh_link].sh_offset, SEEK_SET);
                fread(strtab, 1, shdr_strtab.sh_size, infos.fp);

                // 10 is arbitrary, I did not figure out how to get the number of entries yet
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
                printf("%s\n", strtab + symtab[i].st_name); // .stname reads 0
            }
```

EDIT:

for every `symtab[i]` this is what I get. Seems like I made a mistake somewhere...

I have verified with `nm` and other tools to make sure symbols and names are well defined.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the st_name is 0, than the entry has no name as described in the manuals

```
st_name
An index into the object file's symbol string table, which holds the character 
representations of the symbol names. If the value is nonzero, it represents a string table
index that gives the symbol name. Otherwise, the symbol table entry has no name.
```

It's normal for some entries to be 0 at the beginning of the table.

If you are sure that there are symbols with names, try to read all entries and see if you are finding them correctly. The number of entries is `shdr_symtab.sh_size / sizeof(Elf64_Sym)`

Also, replace `shdr_tab[shdr_symtab.sh_link].sh_offset` with `shdr_strtab.sh_offset` as follows:

```
                char *strtab = malloc(shdr_strtab.sh_size);
                fseek(infos.fp, shdr_strtab.sh_offset, SEEK_SET);
                fread(strtab, 1, shdr_strtab.sh_size, infos.fp);
```

Comment: thanks for the hint. I've edited my question with relevant information.

Comment: @SadAdl replace shdr_tab[shdr_symtab.sh_link].sh_offset with shdr_strtab.sh_offset